# Bring back end user setup screen OEM install

Tags: boot, lubuntu, oem

I did an OEM install, and everything worked as expected.

On boot, it showed a setup window intended for the end user, for some reason, I decided to close the window and now, it boots to the login screen instead of the setup screen.

How can I get the setup screen to show up again without having to redo the OEM install?

OS is Lubuntu 16.04